# How to check if current date time is within weekend period

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to create some kind of restaurant system that shows a different menu when it's the weekends.

The problem I'm having is how do I write my condition statement to decide the current date time is within Friday 5pm and Sunday 11:59pm. While I can quite easily determine the day of the week, I'm having problems when the time range comes into play.

Any help would be greatly appreciated please. Thanks!

Comment: What does your code look like now? Just add a condition: if it's Friday, is it before or after 5pm?

Comment: Is your problem an algorithm-design issue (i.e. you can't figure out how to do it on paper) or a question about how to use PHP's date functions and classes to find out the time of day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
$hourofweek = (date("N") * 24) + date("H");

if($hourofweek > (5*24 + 17)) {
   // it's the weekend
}
```

Note: date("N") follows a weird convention of Sunday being the last day of the week (7) so there's no need for a less-than check.

Comment: You dont need `* 7` up there. `date("N") follows a weird convention of Sunday being the last day of the week (7)` why this is weird? I guess you are from US? It's not weird to the rest of the world ;-) E.g. in Russia we all have been learned that Sunday is a last day of the week, I think it is so in many European countries as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I thought I did. =S

Comment: No, I believe 5 is correct. In the question he says he wants to start the weekend at 5pm on Friday.

Comment: @alfasin, it shouldn't ;) 5*24 = 00:00 of Saturday + 17 = 17:00 of Saturday

Comment: That sounds like great I shall try that out when I get to my desk later. Should it also be checking for > (4*24 + 17) instead of 5 since Friday is "not over yet"?

Comment: No, 5*24+17 is correct. If you look at the manual on PHP date it shows that N is the current day of the week:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
In some ways this is an inelegant solution because values less than 24 will never occur, but that's just the way date("N") works.